# How to set and get variable value in Azure Synapse or Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have created a pipeline with [Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory), say, `activity1`in Azure Synapse Analytics workspace that loads the following `JSON` to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 (ADLSGen2) using `source` as a `REST Api` and `Sink` (destination) as `ADLSGen2`. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory).

**MyJsonFile.json** (stored in ADLSGen2)

```
{"file_url":"https://files.testwebsite.com/Downloads/TimeStampFileName.zip"}
```

In the same pipeline, I need to add an `activity2` that reads the `URL` from the above `JSON`, and `activity3` that loads the `zip` file (mentioned in that URL) to the same `Gen2 storage`.

**Question**: How can we add an `activity2` to the existing pipeline that will get the `URL` from the above `JSON` and then pass it to `activity3`? Or, are there any better suggestions/solutions to achieve this task.

**Remarks**: I have tried [Set Variable Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-set-variable-activity) (shown below) by first declaring a variable in the pipeline and the using that variable, say, `myURLVar` in this activity, but I am not sure how to dynamically set the value of myURLVar to the value of the URL from the above JSON. Please NOTE the Json file name (MyJsonFile.json) is a constant, but zip file name in the URL is dynamic (based on timestamp), hence we cannot just hard code the above url.

[image]

Comment: You could try to add a look up activity whose source is the MyJsonFile.json stored in ADLSGen2 after the Copy Activity. Then trough the look up activity's output to get the file_url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Steve Zhao mentioned in the comments, use `lookup` activity to get the data from the **JSON** file and extract the required URL from the lookup output value using `set variable` activity.

- Connect the `lookup` activity to the sink dataset of previous copy data activity.

[image]

**Output** of lookup activity:

[image]

- I have used the **substring** function in set activity to extract the URL from the lookup output.

  ```
  @replace(substring(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'"',''),'}',''),'{',''),indexof(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'"',''),'}',''),'{',''),'http'),sub(length(string(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'"',''),'}',''),'{',''))),indexof(replace(replace(replace(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value),'"',''),'}',''),'{',''),'http'))),']','')
  ```

[image]

Check the **output of set variable**:

[image]

**Set variable output value**:

[image]

Comment: How did you test to make sure that `Set-Variable` activity indeed got the required URL from the lookup output value? I have used `Lookup` and `Set variable` activities in the same order. The pipeline also runs fine. But I could not figure out to verify that the `set variable`  activity got the required URL or not.

Comment: You can check the output of the set variable in OUTPUT properties in the pipeline. Updated my answer with a snip to check set variable output.

Comment: Got it - thank you (+1).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without needing complex string manipulation to parse the JSON. The caveat is that the JSON file needs to be formatted such that there are no line breaks (or that each line break represents a new record).

First setup a `Lookup` activity that loads the JSON file in the same way as @NiharikaMoola-MT's answer shows.

Then for the `Set Variable` activity's `Value` setting, use the following dynamic expression: `@activity('<YourLookupActivityNameHere>').output.firstRow.file_url`